# AngularJS reevaluates bindings when I don't change anything in the scope

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

I need to update a little digital 'clock' in my Angular app.
I'm using the following code in my controller:

```
        $scope.time = new Date();
        var interval = $timeout(function updateTime() {
            console.log("Update time");
            $scope.time = new Date();
            $scope.formattedTimeValue = WBUtils.formattedTime($scope.time);
            interval = $timeout(updateTime, 1000);
        }, 1000);
```

I display `formattedTimeValue` in a little div in my html using `{{formattedTimeValue}}` expression.
I also have an ng-repeat directive formatting data using filters. My problem is those filters get reevaluated every second. I can't understand why. I've changed my interval function to the following but filters still get reevaluated:

```
            var interval = $timeout(function updateTime() {
              console.log("Update time");
              interval = $timeout(updateTime, 1000);
            }, 1000);
```

Can someone please explain to me why my filter gets evaluated each second for each object (unchanged) in ng-repeat. The filter currently looks like this:

```
module.filter('formatLogRecord', function () {
    return function (log) {
        console.log("Filtering");
        return "";
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The angular $timeout service includes making a call to `$apply` for the whole $rootScope ( https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.2.0rc1/src/ng/timeout.js#L10 ), which will cause a new digest and re-evaluate the filters. If that's not what you want, just use a plain js setTimeout instead and wrap only the bits dealing with scope in `$scope.$apply` yourself.

Comment: Thanks, that was really helpful, I feel ashamed now, could have gotten into the source code myself and figured it out.

Comment: I think it's possible to skip apply call using the third argument to $timeout.

Answer (score 1):

First, $timeout causes a $scope.$digest() when the timer reaches 0, which re-evaluates the bindings. Second, each time you iterate your time you are changing the value of $scope.time and $scope.formattedTimeValue, both of which will cause Angular to run a digest and re-evaluate your values.